# docker apt-get update error

Tags: node.js, docker

My dockerfile

```
FROM node:argon


# Set the locale
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

9 out of 10 times, it can not be built with the error below.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 73.95 MB
Step 1 : FROM node:argon
 ---> 10a26800d95a
Step 2 : RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
 ---> Running in 5a41dd8ab15e
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [390 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 5.153.231.35 80]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [142 kB]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages

Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages

Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.231.35 80]
Fetched 9808 kB in 15s (615 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 5.153.231.35 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.231.35 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get clean && apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Nothing changes, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile works perfect from my machine. I guess it is caused by the network connectivity. So please check if you are behind a firewall, and whether you need to set a proxy in order to access the Internet. If so, please add this command into your Dockerfile in front of `RUN apt-get` commands to set proxy `ENV http_proxy 'http://<server-address>:<port>'`

Answer (score 3):

I built your Dockerfile multiple times without issue. Try restarting your Docker service / instance / machine.

You may be having network issues, as the problem is intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

This happend to me just due to the simple reason that my system clock was in past (not synced). fixing the time made this error disappear.